# How would i generate a list from another list in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to iterate the whole list and based on certain values generate multiple lists out of that original list

here is an example

```
<div *ngIf="location.items?.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let item of location.items">
        <div *ngIf="item.type === 'a'">
            #create another list of items with type 'a'
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="item.type === 'b'">
            #create another list of items with type 'b'
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

can someone please explain how would i do that

Comment: Please share the data you are trying to display

Comment: Don't do that in the template. Generate the two arrays in your TypeScript code, and display those two lists in the template. `this.aList = location.items.filter(item => item.type === 'a'); this.bList = location.items.filter(item => item.type === 'b');`

Comment: If you need a separated list, ideally way is to do it component.ts rather than on html. In ES6 you can use filter to separate a list of values,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

If you need things to be displayed in different styles based on a condition in html, you can use NgIf directive

https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best not to try to do this in your template. In your component where `location` exists, you could create your desired lists using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

For example to get, `item` of `location.items` with `item.type === 'a'`, we would do

```
const aItems = location.items.filter(item => item.type === 'a');    // only contains items of type a
const bItems = location.items.filter(item => item.type === 'b');    // only of type b
// ... and so on
```

And now in your template, just separate the lists into different `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aItems">
    <div>
        {{item.someField}}
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of bItems">
    <div>
        {{item.someField}}
    </div>
</div>
```